# Rails 4 - rake db:migrate on a live website with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

Simple question, but I can't seem to find an answer.

**On a live production site that has active users at all times of the day, what is the best way to migrate the database without going into maintenance mode?**

In my situation, I've added a few columns to my database and want to migrate the changes up. Normally, I would simply run `heroku maintenance:on`, then migrate my changes, then turn maintenance off -- obviously this will avoid any exceptions/errors in between the push and the migration. Now that I consistently have active users, I feel there has to be a way to do this seamlessly -- that is not kicking anyone off and throwing a maintenance screen at them.

Would appreciate any help. Please link any docs if this is talked about somewhere -- seriously can't find anything.

Comment: I think what you want is something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500530/blue-green-deployment-on-heroku-or-another-cloud-platform-as-a-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A database migration strategy with zero downtime depends on various factors:

- Do you want to add, remove or rename a column? Do you need to change a columns type or want to add an index?
- How big is the table, how long will the migration take?
- Is the table heavily used or is it possible to disable just this model.
- What database engine do you use? Some databases lock the whole table even for minor changes.
- What level of access right does the database user have? Some tools (like [Soundcloud's lhm](https://github.com/soundcloud/lhm) needs more rights than a usual Rails app.

You will find some example how to add or remove columns in this [readme](https://github.com/ankane/strong_migrations).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Heroku pre-boot](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preboot). It may be exactly what you are looking for.